# Use of で in 小川さんは語学が得意で、フランス語もイ夕リア語もできます

Tags: particle-で

In 'All About Particles', I have come across the sentence:

> 小川さんは語学が得意で、フランス語もイ夕リア語もできます。
>
> (Ogawa is good at languages, he can speak both French and Italian.)

What is the use of で in this sentence? I can kind of understand it as placing the second part in context, however I would have used です, would that also work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

で like this is essentially the conjunctive form of です. You can make two separate statements: 「Aです。Bです。」 Or you can make one statement that combines the two: 「Aで、Bです。」In this usage pattern, as you note, the A part provides the context, and the で functions a bit like the English "**it is** A **and** it is B".

Answer (score 2):

“で” or “ので”　is a conjunction equivalent to and, so, as, and because, as in,

彼女は料理が好き**で**、特にパスタ料理が得意です
- She is a good cooker **and** her specialty is pasta dishes.

ウイスキーを一杯飲ん**で**それから出かけました
- He had a gulp of a glass of whiskey **and** went out.

彼は勉強家**で**、中国語を3年間で完全にマスターしました
- He is a hard-worker, **so** he completely mastered Chinese in three years.

彼は言い間違えた**ので**訂正しました
- He misspoke. **So** he corrected it

彼は骨折**で**入院しました
- **Because of** a fracture, he got hospitalized.

彼女は愛想がいい**ので**皆に好かれています
- **Because** (as) she is so amiable, she is liked by everybody.

Comment: 3つ目の例ですが、「3年間で」ではなく「勉強家で」の「で」を太字にしようと思われたのではないですか？「3年間で」の「で」は、助動詞ではなく助詞ですので。　また、5つ目の例の「骨折で」の「で」も、助動詞ではなく助詞‌​ですが。